# XMLSerialization with multiple namespaces - backwardscompatibility

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have a version 1.0 of an application with a class like:

```
class MyBaseDTO
{
   [XmlElementAttribute(DataType="base64Binary", IsNullable=true, ElementName="Data")]
   public byte[] Data{get;set}
}
```

and a subclass

```
class MySubDTO
{
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType="base64Binary", IsNullable=true, ElementName="MoreData")]
    public byte[] MoreData{get;set}
}
```

now in version 1.1 I want to move MySubDTO.MoreData to MyBaseDTO.
The problem is that when I communicate with a 1.0 server with a 1.1 client the MoreData is never serialzed because the xml looks like:

```
<a:MyBaseDTO i:type="b:MySubDTO"><a:Data>...</a:Data><b:MoreData>...</b:MoreData></a:MyBaseDTO>
```

If I add

```
class MyBaseDTO
{
   [XmlElementAttribute(DataType="base64Binary", IsNullable=true, ElementName="Data")]
   public byte[] Data(){get;set}
   [XmlElementAttribute(DataType="base64Binary", IsNullable=true, ElementName="MoreData", NameSpace="MyBaseDTO")]
   public byte[] MoreData(){get;set}
}
```

It works of course but I would like it to be possible to understand that the MoreData could have two different namespaces. I'm using WCF to communicate between the webservices and using DataContractSerializer to serialize the objects on the server side. Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- I think that this is the kind of scenario that IExtensibleDataObject (extension data) was designed for! The idea is that if the v1 of the data contract is decorated with the extension data interface, it will automagically ignore, store, and round-trip data from future revisions of the data contract -- including future unknown types -- without any issues.

To enable round-tripping for a particular type, your type should the IExtensibleDataObject interface. The interface contains one property, ExtensionData (returning the ExtensionDataObject type). The property stores any data from future versions of the data contract that is unknown to the current version. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string fullName;
    private ExtensionDataObject theData;

    public virtual ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get { return theData; }
        set { theData = value; }
    }
}
```

When the WCF infrastructure encounters data that is not part of the original data contract, it stores and preserves the data in this property. It is not processed in any other way except for temporary storage. If the object is returned back to where it originated, the original (unknown) data is also returned.

You can always turn off this round-tripping feature, either by setting ignoreExtensionDataObject to true in the DataContractSerializer constructor or by setting the IgnoreExtensionDataObject property to true on the ServiceBehaviorAttribute. It does have a performance hit, so if you don't need it, I'd turn it off.

- The above guidance does require that you switch over to DataContractSerializer. If you can't do that for this type, you may have to use an IDataContractSurrogate to translate this XML type to a DataContract type that looks like exactly what you do.  also lets you do custom JSON serialization and deserialization on a per-type or per-object basis.